# Why do apps like Whatsapp and Viber create their own accountType in Contacts in android?

Tags: android

If we look in our contacts in android then there is a RawContact created for whatsapp and simil;arily for Viber as well. What is the need to do so?

Can't whatsapp and viber use the existing RawContacts in android?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the application masks non-users of the application in our contacts from being called or so.

Comment: For this they can create their own db table and point the raw contact id of existing android contact. Why do they need to create their own?

Answer (score 0):

the raw contacts is reserved for android only + its easier to manage and separate contacts that way

Answer (score 0):

They create sync adapter which create the account. It makes easy to sync contacts with their database.
From android docs- 
`The sync adapter framework requires each sync adapter to have an account type.`

Read more about [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Comment: What is the basic need to create a sync adapter? Can't they use the raw contacts of android?

Comment: The contacts are not only saved in your phone but also on their servers.